# Include post title wordpress in replace SQL

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I need something similar to this:

```
$titulo = get_the_title( $post_id );
update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'>Episódio','>$titulo Episódio');
```

I know that this function is wrong, but it is a way of exemplifying what I need.
I need to get the title wordpress and use with the SQL replace function

Comment: Can you explain clearly what do you want to replace?

Comment: create a variable with the correct title, the execute the query. You're not actually executing a query in your example

Comment: I need to include the wordpress title in the replacement line. I do not know the correct function for this, so I exemplified it in Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Backup your database** first before trying this. Add this to your theme's 'functions.php', **run only once and delete**. Please note that this will replace all occurrences of 'Episodio' with '[post title] Episodio'. Keep FTP in hand since you may not able to access 'functions.php' before deleting this code.

```
<?php
function replace_string()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT *  FROM  $table_name  ORDER BY ID" );
    foreach ( $results as $postobj )
    {
        $post_content = str_replace( 'Episodio', $postobj->post_title.' Episodio', $postobj->post_content);

        $selectd = "UPDATE {$table_name} SET `post_content` = '".$post_content."' WHERE ID='".$postobj->ID."'";
        $wpdb->get_results($selectd);
    }
    die();
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'replace_string' );
?>
```

Comment: The above code will update the content of particular post in database - what do you want to return?

Comment: If you refresh the page again, you can see the updated content. Make sure that you have correct 'find' & 'replace' strings.

Comment: There are several posts with the term ">Episodio". I activated the Wordpress error log: 
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: post_id

Comment: Oh then you need to loop - I'll update the answer shortly. Can you confirm that title would be individual post title or same for all?

Comment: Ok, individual post title

Comment: Check my updated answer and don't try if you do not have database backup or FTP.

Comment: Thanks, you are amazing!